# How to get every single row data from the excel for every single test script using Selenium and apache poi - automation test

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, testng

This is my script

```
@Test(dataProvider = "loginData")
    public void CorrectAccount(String username, String password){
        WebDriver driver = getDriver();
        driver.get(Url.currentUrl("LOGIN_PAGE"));
        LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
        loginPage.inputUsernameMC(username)
                .inputPasswordMC(password)
                .clickBtnLoginMC();

    }
public void IncorrectAccount(String username, String password){
WebDriver driver = getDriver();
        driver.get(Url.currentUrl("LOGIN_PAGE"));
        LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
        loginPage.inputUsernameMC(username)
                .inputPasswordMC(password)
                .clickBtnLoginMC();
    }
    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] loginData(){

        String excelFileName = "dataLogin.xlsx";
        File excelFileLocation = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/data/" + excelFileName);
        String sheetName = "heroku";
        int startRowIndex = 1;
        int startColumnIndex = 0;
        ExcelReader excelReaderUtils = new ExcelReader(excelFileLocation, sheetName, startRowIndex, startColumnIndex);
        int totalRow = excelReaderUtils.getTotalRow();
        int totalColumn = excelReaderUtils.getTotalColumn();

        Object[][] loginData = new Object[totalRow - startRowIndex][totalColumn];
        for(int startRow = startRowIndex; startRow < totalRow; startRow++){
            for (int startColumn = startColumnIndex; startColumn < totalColumn; startColumn++){
                loginData[startRow - startRowIndex][startColumn] = excelReaderUtils.getCellvalue(startRow, startColumn);
            }
        }
        return loginData;
    }
```

this is my excelReader

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

import static org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.*;

public class ExcelReaderUtils {
    private File excelFileLocation;
    private Sheet sheet;
    private FileInputStream fis;
    private Workbook workbook;
    private String sheetName;
    private int startRow;
    private int totalRow;
    private int startColumn;
    private int totalColumn;
    public ExcelReaderUtils(File excelFileLocation, String sheetName, int startRow, int startColumn){
        this.excelFileLocation = excelFileLocation;
        this.sheetName = sheetName;
        this.startColumn = startColumn;
        this.startRow = startRow;
        try{
            fis = new FileInputStream(excelFileLocation);
            workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
            sheet = workbook.getSheet(this.sheetName);
            totalRow = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
            totalColumn = sheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
            fis.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public String getCellvalue(int rowNumber, int colNumber){
        Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNumber);
        Cell cell = row.getCell(colNumber);
        String cellValue = "";
        CellType cellType = cell.getCellType();

        if(cellType.equals(cellType.STRING))
            cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
        if(cellType.equals(cellType.NUMERIC)) {
            NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
            cellValue = String.valueOf(nf.format(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
        }
        return cellValue;
    }
    public int getTotalRow() {
        return this.totalRow;
    }

    public int getTotalColumn() {
        return this.totalColumn;
    }
```

My excel:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BVcf.png)

How can I get username and password of row 1 in my excel for CorrectAccount method and get username and password of row 2 for IncorrectAccount
How can I get username and password of row 1 in my excel for CorrectAccount method and get username and password of row 2 for IncorrectAccount

Comment: have you tried using your ExcelReaderUtils getCellvalue ?

Comment: I tried it and get all value in excel successful but I can not use every single username and password for every single testscript